# Regression tested with gvlma (with r) and all decisions not satisfied(question should not be r related?) ->What can I do?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I am doing a regression in r right now and my issue is that after I tested the regression with gvlma all the assumptions tested were not satisfied:

|  | Value | Value | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Global Stat | 6.841e+06 | 0.000e+00 | Assumption NOT satisfied |
| Skewness | 8.514e+04 | 0.000e+00 | Assumption NOT satisfied |
| Kurtosis | 6.755e+06 | 0.000e+00 | Assumption NOT satisfied |
| Link Function | 6.202e+01 | 3.442e-15 | Assumption NOT satisfied |
| Heteroscedasticity | 1.250e+03 | 0.000e+00 | Assumption NOT satisfied |

That the assumption for normal distributed data is not satisfied is (as I would say) quite normal for real data. Therefore I am doing a bootstrapping but I don't even know if that is "enough".

I am not quite sure if I can even use the model at all or if I could do some corrections or modify the regression so that it "works".

If any more information is needed just let me know :)

Edit:

I have data for companies in the USA. I am doing a regression on the effects of interest rates on marketing spending.

My model looks like this:

```
lm.05 <-lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py  
           + DummySIC1 + DummySIC2 + DummySIC3 + DummySIC4 + DummySIC5
           + DummySIC6 + DummySIC7
            , data=Relevante_V03)
```

marketingspending= marketing spending, intr= interest rate, sale_py_at_py= sale(t-1)/asset(t-1), R_at_py= 1/asset(t-1), Dummy variable are for the segment they work in.

I wanted to add also values like retained earnings or debt, but then the gvlma fails telling me:

> System is singular for the computer: reciprocal condition number =
> 8.39456e-29

-> with higher or lower numbers depending on the variable (example is debt)

Edit No2:

I trimmed my data set to 3632 obj. and 38 variables. There is a lot of variation because there are both large companies and small companies. Therefore, I had also chosen the segment as a dummy. And 1/asset(t-1) to include the size difference.

Here some example data (just used summary() on the data):

|  | asset | sale | dt | at_py |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Min. | 1.120e+05 | 1.434e+05 | 1.022e+04 | 9.747e+04 |
| 1st Qu. | 5.475e+06 | 4.395e+06 | 4.714e+05 | 4.652e+05 |
| Median | 1.307e+07 | 1.063e+07 | 2.523e+06 | 1.173e+06 |
| Mean | 5.415e+07 | 4.129e+07 | 1.224e+07 | 4.842e+07 |
| 3st Qu. | 3.388e+07 | 2.652e+07 | 7.927e+06 | 3.045e+07 |
| Max | 3.753e+09 | 2.805e+09 | 1.173e+09 | 3.753e+09 |

Edit 3:

I now plotted the data and looked for extrem values and cancels them out. So my data now has 3569 obs. and 38 variables.

Also I took the `log()` of every "normal" variable (not from the dummy variables).

To that the question: has someone please studies or sources how (why) this is done

Afterwards my regression looks like this:

```
lm.05 <-lm(log(marketingspending) ~ log(intr) + log(sale_py_at_py) + log(R_at_py)  
           + log(p_con) + log(txt) 
           + DummySIC1 + DummySIC2 + DummySIC0 + DummySIC4 + DummySIC5
           + DummySIC6 + DummySIC7
            , data=r1)
```

But still heteroscedasticity was not accepted from `gvlma()` and also the global stat:

|  | Value | p-Value | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Global Stat | 50.3755 | 3.014e-10 | Assumption NOT satisfied |
| Skewness | 2.3720 | 1.235e-01 | Assumptions acceptable |
| Kurtosis | 0.6177 | 4.319e-01 | Assumptions acceptable |
| Link Function | 0.2853 | 5.933e-01 | Assumptions acceptable |
| Heteroscedasticity | 47.1005 | 6.744e-12 | Assumption NOT satisfied |

Therefore I tried the following:

```
BC_m_s <- BoxCoxTrans(r1$marketingspending)
r1 <- cbind(r1, m_s_BC = predict(BC_m_s, r1$marketingspending))

lm.05 <-lm(m_s_BC ~ log(intr) + log(sale_py_at_py) + log(R_at_py)  
               + log(p_con) + log(txt) 
               + DummySIC1 + DummySIC2 + DummySIC0 + DummySIC4 + DummySIC5
               + DummySIC6 + DummySIC7
                , data=r1)
```

But that did not change anything :/

Has someone a solution for me so that Global Stat and Heteroscedasticity will be accepted? (and if possible with a study or sources how (why) this is done)

Some information about the data:

|  | asset | sale | dt | at_py |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Min. | `1.120e+05` | 1.434e+05 | 1.022e+04 | 9.747e+04 |
| 1st Qu. | `5.475e+06` | 4.395e+06 | 4.714e+05 | 4.652e+05 |
| Median | `1.307e+07` | 1.063e+07 | 2.523e+06 | 1.173e+06 |
| Mean | `5.415e+07` | 4.129e+07 | 1.224e+07 | 4.842e+07 |
| 3st Qu. | `3.388e+07` | 2.652e+07 | 7.927e+06 | 3.045e+07 |
| Max | `3.753e+09` | 2.805e+09 | 1.173e+09 | 3.753e+09 |

(had to make the second column to code because it did not let me post??? hahaha)

Comment: Your skewness and kurtosis are enormous.  It would therefore help to have a more complete description of your data and your model, especially concerning any apparent outlying data.

Comment: I added some information. Do you need more? And if so what kind of information?

Comment: So far that's helpful, because the warning message tells you nothing of the output can be trusted!  Could you supply a *basic, simple* description?  That would include things like the amount of data you have and perhaps some indication of the typical values and spreads of each of the variables.

Comment: Okay hope this time I added enough information :)

Comment: That helps.  I wonder (1) whether any of the values of `asset(t-1)` might be zero or tiny, thereby creating unusual values; (2) what exactly the `DummySIC` variables are.  This sounds like a set of categorical variables and sometimes a tiny count for some combinations of such variables can create problems.

Comment: (2)DummySIC means that I divided them into 8 groups of segments the company is working in (Group 0-7). And if the company is in the Group 1 it gets a 1 for DummySIC1 and 0 in every other Dummy-group. (1) I will add the column for that